# How is it possible to pass move-only types (e.g. std::unique_ptr) by value?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, move-semantics, pass-by-value

If we take `std::unique_ptr` as an example, the prevailing wisdom for passing move-only types into a sink function (e.g. a constructor that takes ownership of the pointer) is to pass it in by value and move it at the call site. E.g.

```
class Sink {
    public:
        Sink(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo) : foo(std::move(foo)) {}

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo;
};
```

How is this possible? Shouldn't the compiler be able to deduce immediately that `std::unique_ptr` is a move-only type and reject the use of `Sink(std::unique_ptr<Foo>)`? Is there something special about the pass-by-value rules here (i.e. that things passed by value are copied into that functions activation frame)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `foo` doesn't have to be copied into, it can be moved into as well

Comment: That'd be nice, but unfortunately (or as a quirk of history) the "move-able" concept is fairly recent and had to be bolted onto an already very well seasoned language.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x that was the missing insight here, I had always thought that passing by value invokes the copy constructor, though I now know that that will depend on the type of the value passed in at the call site (copy constructor for lvalues and rvalues without move constructors, move constructor for rvalues with move constructors).

Answer (score 3):

Of course this works, as long as you either pass an rvalue to the constructor of Sink or you move the argument.  In both cases the move constructor, rather than the (deleted) copy constructor will be called for the argument.

*N.B.:* I don't think `std::move` is a good idea here because then you'll have a moved-from object floating around in your function.  Static analysis can probably spot this but it's a source of bugs.

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo {};

class Sink {
    public:
        Sink(std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo) : foo(std::move(foo)) {}

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo;
};

int main() {
    // rvalue
    Sink s(std::make_unique<Foo>());

    // std::move (can be dangerous)
    auto f = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    Sink ss(std::move(f));

    // By value is not allowed
    auto ff = std::make_unique<Foo>();
  //Sink sss(ff); // BOOM!
}
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AvvvGN8V0riDSNzw)

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for your comment but I'm not sure whether I understand it correctly.  Please feel free to edit my answer for clarification.

Comment: Your update explains what happened well enough for me.

Comment: "moved-from object is undefined behaviour" no, that is false.  There are ways to use moved-from objects that invoke UB, but the same is true of non-moved-from objects.

Comment: moved-from objects are in a valid but indeterminate state.

Comment: So would it be more accurate to say that pass-by-value doesn't always invoke the copy constructor, but rather invokes either the copy or move constructor depending on whether the value passed in is an lvalue or rvalue reference?

Comment: @AUD_FOR_IUV As you see it depends on the kind of value.  Rvalues invoke the move constructor (if there is one, otherwise copy), lvalues invoke the copy constructor.

Comment: Wow that explains a lot. I had always been told that passing by value unconditionally invokes the copy constructor (because I guess that was the case pre-C++11) and never stopped to consider that the behavior might be different when move semantics come into play. Thanks!

Comment: "the state of a moved-from object is indeterminate" this is also false.  There are moved-from objects with indeterminate state, but there are also not-moved from objects with indeterminate state, and moved-from objects (both inside, and outside of `std`) whose state is determined completely.  `unique_ptr<T>` is one of those types whose objects' moved-from state is completely determinate.

Comment: @Yakk Okay, I'm definitely not language lawyer enough to argue about that, so I just removed this sub-sentence.  I hope you agree that having moved-from objects around it is a potential source of bugs.